# Stale closures with react hooks and click events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, react-hooks, closures

I have created a codesandbox for easier debugging:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-dirac-nh4iz?file=/src/App.tsx

I have built a DataList component that I use like:

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const countRef = useRef(count);

  const handleSelect = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    countRef.current = count + 1;
    console.log({ count });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>Stale closures prevent the count state from displaying correctly</p>
      <DataList.List label="testing">
        {data.map((d) => (
          <DataList.Item key={d} onSelect={handleSelect}>
            {d} {count}
          </DataList.Item>
        ))}
      </DataList.List>
    </>
  );
}
```

All of the functionality is handled inside of a `useListBox` hook, which includes taking the `onSelect`  prop from each child and binding that to a click event on the List itself. However, a stale closure is preventing the `count` value from updating.

I would appreciate any help with this, as stale closures have yet to click for me.

I suspect, I need the `onSelect` to be a dependency on the `handleClickEvent` callback, but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way your `useEffectOnMount` is defined. You need to factor in changes even after the mount whenever your `children` update as well. Change it from `useEffectOnMount` to `useEffect` and things will work :-

Forked sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-fog-inv8h?file=/src/components/DataList/DataList.tsx

Comment: I'm somewhere in between feeling stupid and encouraged that it was such a simple thing. Thank you for taking the time to help out :)